# Module or API to get random phrases in specific languages

Tags: python, string, api, module

I wanna build a Python script and I need to get random entire phrases to be saved on a list
Is there any API or module that would give me random entire phrases in selected languages? , let's say for example, from a website, online international database of phrases, quotes, etc...
Let's say for example:

```
phrase = get_random_spanish_phrase('es')
print(phrase)
```

it would do something like

```
esta es una frase en español
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the module `wonderwords`, to install:

```
pip install wonderwords
```

Wonderwords allows Python to interact with a database and to generate random words or phrases in English. To answer the question, I found a solution to get the phrase or word in any language using `googletrans` API, then I did the following:

First, I started importing both modules, and from the module `wonderwords` I imported the function `RandomSentence` that would request a random sentence and return it. From the module `googletrans` I imported the `Translator` function that would help me translate the sentence generated from `wonderwords`, passing the sentence to another variable and translating the content from the variable.
The code would look like this

```
from googletrans import Translator
from wonderwords import RandomSentence

translator = Translator() #defining the translator object
sentence = RandomSentence() #defining the random sentence

'''now we create another variable that would store the translated random sentence in the language that we want'''

translated_sentence = translator.translate(sentence, src='en', dest='es') 
'''here we are passing as parameters 1) the sentence that we want to translate 2) the language of the source sentence (that in this case is on English) 3)the language that we want to translate to, (in this case is Spanish)'''

#finally, we convert that translated sentence into a string

translated_wanted_sentence = translated_sentence.text 
'''we get the translated_sentence converted into a string with the .text method'''
```